# How to remove navigation header padding and margin in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm on expo and going back and forth about this. I'm trying to clean the header part on top of my contents as well as the bottom part. When I ran the code without the navigation container, everything works fine as designed, but now I have to route new screens and bind to the buttons, I can't remove it. I tried everything from the main container stylesheet setting margin to 0 and padding to 0. I have and Globalstyle as well to shove all components to a clear clearn with proper margins.

[image]

If you take a look, there are dark bars on the top and the bottom part of the screen. I wanted to remove specifically that.

```
export default function App() {

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

 return (
    <NavigationContainer style={GlobalStyles.NotchAware}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
          >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Welcome}
          options={{
            headerShown:false,
            }}
          />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
 )  ;
}
```

with this mere styling for the app.js

```
NotchAware: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 25 : 0,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,
},
```

These are some of the component code and styling.

```
 export default function Welcome() {
 const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

 const nextAction = () => {
 }

 const skipAction = () => {
 
 }
 return (
 <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <StatusBar style="auto" />
  <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
    <WelcomeCard />
  </View>

  <View style={styles.cardTextContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.cardText}>Let’s make learning more fun than ever.</Text>
  </View>

  <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.skipButton} onPress={skipAction}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Skip</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View>
            <Dots length={2} active={active} />
        </View>
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.nextButton} onPress={nextAction}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Next</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity> 
        </View>
  </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
  );
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 50,
    marginBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
 }, 



buttonContainer : {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
},

cardTextContainer : {
    width: 221,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
},

cardContainer : {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},

cardText: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontSize: 18,
    lineHeight: 21,

},

skipButton: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#4F74F7',
    width: 81,
    height: 40,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},

nextButton: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#4F74F7',
    width: 81,
    height: 40,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},

buttonText: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: '700',
    fontSize: 15,
    lineHeight: 16,
    color: '#fff'
}
});
```

Comment: `header : null` ?